# Connect to Remote machines through Powershell

Tags: powershell, remote-desktop

We have set of 8 machines which are present in client location. These 8 machines we use for our Automated test executions. Issue is if any one from offshore location connects to these machines via RDP then machine starts displaying locked screen after 15 minutes or so and our automated scripts starts failing or no screenshots are taken.

So I wrote a powershell script to restart this machine (Say Machine 1) remotely and then execute the required bat file which will then trigger the executions. Restart is happening fine and looks like bat file is getting opened as our framework reads the file and status in centralized reporting changes to Executing. Problem is, it remains in executing status only for a long time and if I connect to the machine (i.e Machine 1) to check why it is stuck, machine will open the same way post a restart (i.e Applying policy settings etc, starts loading all the start up programs/ files) and the bat file is not open and even the process is not visible in task manager. So where exactly is my below code getting executed ? Is it in different session. How do I ensure that this bat file is executed successfully and continues to run in the machine and when I connect I am able to see the same.

```
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName MachineName -Credential Username

Restart-Computer -ComputerName MachineName-Force -Credential Username

Set-Location -Path C:\dev\orcas-agent-uft-deployment

Start-Process "cmd" -ArgumentList "/c","C:\dev\AgentUFT\AgentUFT.bat" 
 -WorkingDirectory "C:\dev\AgentUFT"  -WindowStyle Maximized
```

Am I doing something wrong? After restart I wait for 5 mins and then trigger start process

Comment: For an actual Window to open on the remote machine someone must be logged in and the script must be run as the logged in user. This seems like a backwards way to do it, I'd add the `Start-Process` part to a script you start as a scheduled task that runs on the remote computers at startup instead, and add logging/output in the script to see what happens. As for the process, if you add the `-PassThru` parameter to `Start-Process` you will get a process ID you can look for on the remote machine.

Comment: So, what exactly is the problem? Is it the fact that it is stuck in Executing or the fact that it goes to the lock screen? Or, am I just completely off target?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of things...

When you start the interactive session, you terminal prompt should change; for example, connecting to foo:

```
PS C:\> Enter-PSSession -ComputerName 'foo'
[foo]: PS C:\> ....
```

If you aren't seeing similar behavior, I'd think you weren't connected.

I would restart the host then establish a connection to it. I would think (thought I haven't confirmed) restarting the host would break the remote interactive session.

```
Restart-Computer -ComputerName MachineName-Force -Credential Username
Enter-PSSession -ComputerName MachineName -Credential Username
Set-Location -Path C:\dev\orcas-agent-uft-deployment
...
```

I'm not sure the following will work the way you expect. This is going to start a process on the remote computer (not yours).

```
Start-Process "cmd" -ArgumentList "/c","C:\dev\AgentUFT\AgentUFT.bat" 
 -WorkingDirectory "C:\dev\AgentUFT"  -WindowStyle Maximized
```

You won't see the terminal window opened when you login to the host. If you want to see what the session is on the remote machine, type `$PID` then look for that process ID on the remote machine by running the following:

```
Get-Process -Id 72 -ComputerName foo
```

That said, why not just run the commands in the batch from your interactive session? You could also just run the commands individually from `Invoke-Command`. All of these options will give you better optics into errors the script is encountering.

Check out these references...

Powershell Core (PS 6)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-6

Windows Powershell (PS 5.1)
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/learn/remoting/running-remote-commands?view=powershell-5.1